# How Can I read Lens and Creator Tool Data From EXIF by C#

Tags: c#, exif

from the photo I uploaded to Flickr: http://www.flickr.com/photos/onlyvc/4765160904/meta/
It can read the Lens and Creator Tool data from the image, but I can't find any information about these in EXIF 2.1 version.
Does these two values are special written by Canon? If so, where I can read it?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Check out *ExifTool* by Phil Harvey at http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/. The documentation will answer your question, but why do in C# when there is a great tool to do it for you.